# C++/CLI : How to declare template array as method parameters

Tags: c#, c++-cli, declaration, static-methods

I am a newbie to C++/CLI. What is the equivalent of the following C# code in managed C++/CLI for both the header and source file?

```
public static bool ArrayEquals<T>(T[] a, T[] b) 
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the content for the source file:

```
public:
  generic <typename T>
  static bool ArrayEquals(array<T>^ a, array<T>^ b)
  {
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: @Laurent: Just a quick question. What is the difference between using the keyword generic and template in C++/CLI terms?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and kept getting linker errors. Now I know, the keyword generic should be used instead. Thanks Laurent! :)

```
template<typename T>
bool ArrayEquals(List<T>^ a, List<T>^ b)
{
   return true;
}
```