# C++: how to declare template array as function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, methods

Very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838101/c-cli-how-to-declare-template-array-as-method-parameters)

How can I declare template array as a parameter in templated function?

Something like this code:

```
template <unsigned i> void my_func (char (&a)[i]); //yes, I do need that reference
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare an extra template parameter, which contains the type in question.

```
template <typename T, unsigned i>
void my_func (T (&a)[i]);
```